# Binary Image Not Visible From Live Sql Table ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

On my page I have to upload image and immediate after saving it's displaying on `ImageButton` control and `Image` control. It's working local but not on `Stagging Server`.
I have tried by `Image` Datatype and `VARBINARY(MAX)`. In both cases image is not displaying on `stagging server`.

**Local Screenshot**
[image]

**Stagging Server Screenshot**
[image]

Below is my code:

**Html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" /> <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" /><br /><br />
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Width="150px" />
        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" Width="150px"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**vb Code**:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Partial Class testingImage
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim imageurl As String = ""
    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        bindrepeater()
    End Sub

    Sub bindrepeater()
        Using conn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("dsejConnectionString").ConnectionString)
            Using cmdda As New SqlDataAdapter("select imagefile from testingPhototable where id=1", conn)
                Using ds As New DataSet()
                    cmdda.Fill(ds, "t")
                    If (ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0) Then
                        If ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("imagefile").ToString() <> "" Then
                            imageurl = "data:image/jpg;base64," & Convert.ToBase64String(CType(ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("imagefile"), Byte()))
                            ImageButton1.ImageUrl = imageurl
                            Image1.ImageUrl = imageurl
                        End If
                    End If
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim bytes As Byte()
        Using br As BinaryReader = New BinaryReader(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream)
            bytes = br.ReadBytes(FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength)
        End Using

        Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("dsejConnectionString").ConnectionString
        Using conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(constr)
            Dim sql As String = "UPDATE testingPhototable set imagefile=@imagefile where id=1"
            Using cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@imagefile", bytes)
                conn.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                conn.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
        bindrepeater()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Check the `src` property of the `img` tags on your stagging server, what values do you got in there?

Comment: It's binary path value of an image in SRC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my **web.config**

```
<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="DENY"/>
        <add name="Strict-Transport-Security" value="max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" />
        <add name="X-XSS-Protection" value="1; mode=block" />
        <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff" />
        <add name="content-security-policy: frame-ancestors 'none';img-src 'self';object-src 'self';frame-src 'self';child-src 'self';base-uri 'self';"/>
        <add name="Referrer-Policy" value="strict-origin" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

As listed above under `content-security-policy` there is a property `img-src 'self';` this would stopping binary image to get render on control. I have removed this and now it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

As the property name `ImageUrl` is maked from a word like *“Url”* presumes there needs an URL. So, it’s not like the “`src`” attribute on *Client Side* where you can set a source as Base64 String as well.
`ImageUrl` needs a **relative** url like “root/images/image1.jpg” or **absolute** “//somewhere_in_the_net_or_server/anotherpath/specificpath/yourfile.jpg”. Anyway, to achieve what you want, you can set the attribute “src” of your ImageButton1 as the follow line of code shows:

```
ImageButton1.Attributes("src") = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAgAAAAIACAMAAADDpiTIAAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U....................."
```

You can do the same for `Image1` as well

Comment: It's working perfectly on Local but still not working on stagging server. Is there any issue from Stagging Server which would stopping image from displaying? Or may be not publishing properly?

Comment: Make sure you have enabled your mime types by IIS for the extension you are trying to set (.jpg, .png, or .svg etc..) then if nothing happens seems something go wrong when you are getting to get your img by database or during the conversion in bytes.

Comment: Another thing I have to say is that: Why you are invoking a DataSet making things so heavy to do something you can do easily with SqlDataReader?